# std::map override element under certain circumstances at insertion time

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, duplicates, comparator

let's say I have a map whose key is a pair and whose custom comparator guarantees unicity against the first element of that pair.

```
class comparator 
{
    public:
        bool operator()(const std::pair<std::string, std::int>& left,
                        const std::pair<std::string, std::int>& right) 
        { 
            return left.first < right.first;
        }
};

std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::int>, foo, comparator>;
```

Now I'd like this map to be more intelligent than that, if possible.
Instead of being rejected at insertion time in case a key with the same string as first element of the pair already exists, I'd to overwrite the "already existing element" if the pair's integer (.second) of the "possibly going to be inserted element" is bigger.

Of course I can do this by looking in to the map for the key, getting the key details and overwriting it if necessary. 
Alternatively I could adopt a post-insertion approach with a multimap on top of which I would iterate to clean up duplicates keeping just the key with the biggest pair integer.

The question is : can I do that natively by overriding part of the stl implementation ([] operator - insert method) or improving my custom comparator and then simply relying on map's insert method ?

I don't know if this is accepted but we could imagine having a non const comprator which would be able of updating the already stored (key, value) pair under certain circumstances.

Comment: Whatever those "certain circumstances" are, they better only be updating the value, because placed-element key-modifications in an `std::map<>` or `std::set<>` are not supported by the standard.

Comment: Any particular reason you want this as `map<pair<string, int>, foo, comparator>` instead of the more natural `map<string, pair<int, foo> >`? The latter would put the count (or whatever it is) into the *value*, not the key, so modifying it later on is more reasonable. That said, I believe I'd still write this as a separate method or function, with a separate name, simply to keep the code more readable. When users see an `operator[]` used on a map-like thing, they have certain expectations.

Answer (score 1):

ValueThe answer to your question is that you cannot do it.
There are two problems with your proposed implementation:

1. The keys must remain const as they are the index for the map
2. Independent of what the comparator did to the elements it is comparing the `std::map` would still insert the item before or after `left` based on the return of the comparator

The solution to the problem is as suggested by @MvG. Your key should not be paired, it is your value that should be paired.

This has the added benefit that you don't need a custom comparator.

The problem is that you will need a custom inserter:

```
std::pair< int, foo >& tempValue = _myMap[ keyToInsert ];
if( valueToInsert.first >= tempValue.first )
{
    tempValue = valueToInsert;
}
```

Note that this will only work if all the `valueToInsert.first`s that you use are positive, cause the default constructor for an `int` is 0. If you had negative `valueToInsert.first`s the default constructed value pair would be inserted instead of your element.